# accessing multidimensional array with nested object in react native

Tags: react-native

I want accessing multidimensional array in my app. my array is like :-

```
[{"productid":"31369","productname":"Abilene Swivelling ","productcode":"MTN-CLR.OW","selectoptions":[{"OptionName":"Bracket Option","OptionValue":[{"id":"1668","text":"Without Sound Bar Bracket"},{"id":"1669","text":"With Sound Bar Bracket"}]}]}]
```

I want to access selectoptions . I have fetched productid but not able to fetch selectoptions. 
I have tried this:-

```
{this.props.data.map((dataImage,Index)=>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                        <View key={dataImage['productid']} style={productStyle.homeimg1}>                           
                            <Text style={productStyle.title}> {dataImage['productname']}</Text>
                            <Text style={productStyle.pricesecleft}>RRP {dataImage['productrrp']}</Text>
</View>
{dataImage['selectoptions'].map((selecval) =>
<View>
                            <Text>{selecval['OptionName']}</Text></View>

                            )}
  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                )}
```

its not working . return error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must **use return statement** to return data in **map function**

```
   {this.props.data.map((dataImage,Index)=>
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity key={Index}>
                <View key={dataImage['productid']} style={productStyle.homeimg1}>                           
                    <Text style={productStyle.title}> {dataImage['productname']}</Text>
                    <Text style={productStyle.pricesecleft}>RRP {dataImage['productrrp']}</Text>
                </View>
                {
                   console.log(dataImage['selectoptions'])
                   dataImage['selectoptions'].map((selecval, Index2) =>
                    return (
                      <View key={Index2}>
                        <Text>{selecval['OptionName']}</Text>
                        {selecval['OptionValue'].map((optionval, Index3) =>
                          return (
                              <View key={Index3}>
                                <Text>{optionval['text']}</Text>
                              </View>
                          )
                        }
                      </View>
                    )
                )}
      </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
        )                    
     )}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I have tried this & its returning error. 
undefined is not a function (evaluating 't.selectoptions.map(function(e,t) {return i.defult.createElement(I.View,{key:t},i.default.createElement(I.Text,null,e.OptionName))})')

Comment: Try dataImage.selectoptions.map instead of dataImage['selectoptions'].map

Comment: Please make sure Key names in return json and your defined keys are same. here i dont think there is any bug. seems ok to me.

Comment: this is my array [{"productid":"31369","productname":"Abilene Swivelling ","productcode":"MTN-CLR.OW","selectoptions":[{"OptionName":"Bracket Option","OptionValue":[{"id":"1668","text":"Without Sound Bar Bracket"},{"id":"1669","text":"With Sound Bar Bracket"}]}]}]
and its working properly for productid , productname

Comment: if i used this {dataImage['selectoptions']['0']['OptionName']} than its working

Comment: {dataImage['selectoptions'].map((selecval, Index2) =>
                return (
                  <View key={Index2}>
                    <Text>{selecval['OptionName']}</Text>
                  </View>
                )
            )} this will loop your selectoptions again

Comment: to access OptionValue you need to again loop data, can i update code for OptionValue also ?

Comment: yes, I have tried this as you given above in your answer but its returning error to me
{dataImage['selectoptions'].map((selecval, Index2) =>

Comment: now its returning undefined is not a function (evaluating 't.selectoptions.map')

Comment: seems like dataImage['selectoptions'] returning undefined please check that  try console.log(dataImage['selectoptions']) check i have added in answer